# Data Tables colvis with save button for show/hide columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, datatables

I am using Datatables 1.10.9 and colvis  button plugin can  we do something with this plugin such that it updated the table only once after making selection o all columns , like user just hide/show columns by clicking on buttons and somehow save button should update the table only once instead of each time toggling . Or else can  we do it externally from the dialog box and some other coding Because I need to get names of all visible columns in one go to save it in datatbase. And toggling visibility is doing for each button which is not efficient.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         var table;
         // DataTable               
         table = $('#example').dataTable({
             "processing": true,
             stateSave: true,
             "deferRender": true, // to make the search fast         

            dom: 'BRlfrtip',

                     buttons: [
                            {  extend: 'colvisGroup',
                                text: 'Change Layout',
                                collectionLayout: 'fixed two-column'
                            }                     
                         ],             "ajax": {
                 "url": "/my/example.so",
                 "type": "GET"
             },
             "columns": [{
                 "title": "name",
                 "data": "name",
                 "name": "name"
             }, {
                 "title": "addeddate",
                 "data": "addeddate",
                 "name": "added date"
             }]
         });
```